# OpenPGP with Ionic 2 Angular 2 and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, typescript-typings

I am trying to import OpenPgp to an Ionic 2 app that is wrote in Angular 2 and TypeScript.

However, TypeScript is importing the Types as the module instead of the module. OpenPgp is wrote with AMD, ES6 module support, all the things I have tried are not working.

Aside from Encryption in JS, how do I make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the script as javascript. I know that ionic does not use angular-cli yet but they should have a way to add scripts. For with angular-cli project you can do:

add lib to angular-cli.json

```
  "scripts": [
    .....
    "../node_modules/openpgp/dist/openpgp.js"
  ],
```

add a dummy declaration to keep TS happy:

```
 declare var openpgp: any;
```

Comment: Thanks Julia! I gave this a try but I don't have an angular-cli.json, I tried in the package.json as well, did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

This comment has the answer, need to add the openpgp library in the index.html instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/41372258/1161746

```
<script src="assets/scripts/openpgp.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.openpgp.initWorker({ path:'/assets/scripts/openpgp.worker.min.js' });
</script>
```